# Not able to open new tab in Firefox using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using below line of code

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

this is not working.

I'm using Selenium with Java.

I need to open two websites parallelly in the same browser chrome or Firefox.

I have used below line to create new tab but not working

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

If not this then what is the correct way to do so.

Comment: Can you post error if any thrown by code? also have you tried out below javaScript `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");`

Comment: No error is thrown...((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()"); this worked...thanks!!!